# An issue with inference speed while using SageMaker Neo

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am a student studying Sage Maker Neo.
I am working on this tutorial.

Training and Serving with TensorFlow on Amazon SageMaker

https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/aws_sagemaker_studio/frameworks/tensorflow_mnist/tensorflow_mnist.ipynb

What I'm curious about is that the inference speed is similar when using the c5 instance and when using the p2 instance.
Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial doesn't have anything to do with Neo. You can try out Neo using this example - https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker_neo_compilation_jobs/pytorch_torchvision/pytorch_torchvision_neo.ipynb.

Also, SageMaker Inference Recommender is a good tool to standardize the testing of model performance - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/inference-recommender.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31155547)

Comment: @taylor.2317 Based on the question, Hyun would like to learn SageMaker Neo but he is using an example that is not relevant for that purpose and hence I recommended that link. It will be a lot of code if I cut and past the entire content. Furthermore, examples are kept current by the team that manages it as the dependencies change. In this case, adding the link is the right approach IMO.